# How to calculate euclidian distances between each pair of multiple polygons?

Tags: r, shapefile

I am working with one shapefile data that contains multiple polygons (20 polygons for example). I want to calculate the minimum distance between each pair of polygons (1-2,1-3,1-4,2-3,2-4...19-20) so the question is that there are a lot of scripts that used centroids for calculate the distances between polygons, but i want to calculate the closest distance, so i only need points in the border of polygons to calculate the distances. So any idea about how can i make a script that consider all points in the border of a polygon as a same "object" or "point" ? Or how i can calculate the closest distance between all pair of polygons without using centroids?
Thanks in advance!

I tried `st_nearest_points` between one  pair of polygons (but there are imported as a different layers) and after i calculated the distance with st_distance function